# Difference between 'calculating' and 'determining' time/space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

Based on some discussions I've read about complexities and algorithms, it seems that there's a difference between saying '**calculating** time/space complexity' and '**determining** time/space complexity'.

What is the difference, if there is one?

Does **calculating** time/space complexity mean getting the general big O value for the algorithm (Ex: O(n)) and does **determining** time/space complexity mean getting the exact function that models the time/space (Ex: O(n) = 5n + 6)?

Comment: In my opinion, there is only a slight difference that is not relevant in practice. To determine means to find out using any means. To calculate is a special means of determination. But for complexities, there is usually only the way to calculate the complexity. So I would consider both terms equal.

Comment: @NicoSchertler philosophically speaking, in *formalized* mathematical theories, every *determination* is a *calculation*